# Ping server on incoming messages - Office 365

Tags: office365, exchange-server

Is it possible to create a server rule that automatically sends a http request to a webserver when a new mail is received? As far as i can tell i can only do some very simple stuff in the Exchange admin center but not something like this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with transport rule on exchange server.

But you can write a EWS-based script, which will check your inbox every 1/2/5 minutes and if there's a new message, you can script whatever you want.

Script can be executed on exchange server itself or on any other host.

Here are some code examples:

http://prashant-mahajan.blogspot.ru/2015/02/ews-get-email-sent-and-recipients-count.html

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633693%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

http://gsexdev.blogspot.ru/2016/10/ews-basics-accessing-and-using-shared.html